# Incorrect results in SQL statement while using case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm comparing two days ranks. If old day rank > new rank then increased, else decreased, but I'm getting decreased in both the cases

```
 SELECT 
    USERNAME 
    , SUM(IMPROVED) IMPROVED
    , SUM(DECREASED) DECREASED
     , SUM(NoChange) NoChange
    , SUM(TimeLineCOMPLETED) TimeLineCOMPLETED
      , SUM(TLNotCompleted) TLNotCompleted
FROM 
(SELECT (k.keyword)
    ,p.projectname
    ,pa.username
    ,CASE 

        WHEN a.currentposition > b.currentposition
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END IMPROVED
    ,CASE 
        WHEN a.currentposition < b.currentposition
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END  DECREASED
           ,CASE 
        WHEN a.currentposition = b.currentposition
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END NoChange
    ,CASE 
        WHEN pa.KeywordStatus = 'Stopped'
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END TimeLineCOMPLETED
         ,CASE 
        WHEN pa.KeywordStatus = 'InProgress'
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END TLNotCompleted
    ,a.currentposition AS oldposition
    ,b.currentposition AS newposition
    ,pa.KeywordStatus AS TimeLineStatus
    ,k.targetdate
    ,k.positionExp
FROM seo.tbl_keywordposition a
JOIN seo.tbl_keywordposition b ON a.keywordid = b.keywordid
    AND a.psnupdatedate ='10/5/2015' AND b.psnupdatedate ='10/10/2015' LEFT JOIN tbl_keywords k ON k.keywordid = b.keywordid AND a.keywordid = b.keywordid LEFT JOIN tbl_project p ON p.ProjectId = k.ProjId LEFT JOIN tbl_projAssignment pa ON pa.ProjId = p.ProjectId   AND pa.KeywordID = k.keywordid WHERE p.Projectname = 'october_project' AND a.psnupdatedate ='10/5/2015' AND b.psnupdatedate ='10/10/2015'  and pa.KeywordStatus!='NULL' )INNERQUERY GROUP by USERNAME
```

**Sample data**

```
 SELECT * FROM seo.Tbl_KeywordPosition where KeywordId in ('1514','1515')
 PositionId ProjectId   KeywordId   CurrentPosition PsnUpdateDate       
    31592   129           1514        10             2015-10-05           
    31593   129           1514        11             2015-10-10         
    31594   129           1515        10             2015-10-05          
    31595   129           1515         9             2015-10-10
```

**Current output**

```
USERNAME    IMPROVED    DECREASED   NoChange    
Ananth           0          2          0
```

**Desired output**

```
USERNAME    IMPROVED    DECREASED   NoChange    
Ananth         1          1            0
```

Because `keywordid 1514` - old rank 10 and new rank 11 , so it should be decreased.

`keywordid 1515` - old rank 10 and new rank 9 , so it should be increased

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Comment: Is CurrentPosition type numeric?

Comment: that's the problem then '9'>'10'

Comment: so how to solve that

Comment: cast it, see my answer

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! If it's a `CurrentPosition` - that should **definitely** be a **numeric** datatype - not a string!

Comment: agree with marc_s, totally, but we don't know how much control over the data type the user has; so as an interim solution to make the query work I proposed cast

Comment: its mistake that. 1 should make it int as it takes always numeric.@marc_s

Comment: Every time you need to do a CAST, ask yourself if there's something wrong with the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that CurrentPosition is varchar it should be
cast(a.currentpostion as int) vs cast(b.currentposition as int)

Comment: u r simply superb...i got my solution@jayvee

Answer (score 0):

Base on sample and result:

```
SELECT
    A.KeywordId,
    CASE WHEN B.CurrentPosition - A.CurrentPosition > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IMPROVED,
    CASE WHEN B.CurrentPosition - A.CurrentPosition < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS DECREASED,
    CASE WHEN B.CurrentPosition - A.CurrentPosition = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NoChange
FROM
(SELECT * FROM seo.Tbl_KeywordPosition
 WHERE KeywordId IN ('1514','1515') AND PsnUpdateDate = '2015-10-05'
)AS A
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM seo.Tbl_KeywordPosition
                WHERE KeywordId IN ('1514','1515') AND PsnUpdateDate = '2015-10-10'
                ) AS B
        ON A.ProjectId = B.ProjectId AND A.KeywordId = B.KeywordId
```

Comment: keywordID linked name? (such as 1514 is Ananth?)

Answer (score 0):

Also the ON clause of your query "pa.KeywordStatus!='NULL'" will yield bad results and probably you may have to make it pa.KeywordStatus IS NOT NULL